# Weblogic / EjbGen: worker manager configuration

Tags: configuration, weblogic, worker

I want to declare a worker manager to perform some work in managed thread.

Weblogic documentation tells that we can
- declare a global worker manager using the admin console
- declare a local it in an ejb-jar.xml config file.

I want to use the second option. **But my ejb-jar.xml is generated by the ejbgen tool.**

There is no tag in ejbgen that would allow me to declare a worker manager.

So how should I create a local worker manager declaration ?

I have gathered some interesting answers, posted as an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotsome useful answers for this question:

- use the default work manager
  `WorkManager wm = (WorkManager) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/wm/default";`
- use the `weblogic-application.xml` to configure the work manager instead of configuring it in the ejb-jar.xml
- use a shared library (weblogic 9+ feature) that will contains the worker manager declaration.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you defined your Work Manager as documented [here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12840_01/wls/docs103/config_wls/self_tuned.html#wp1069945) in ejb-jar.xml as a `resource-ref`, example below -

```
... 
<resource-ref> 
   <res-ref-name>wm/MyWorkManager</res-ref-name> 
   <res-type>commonj.work.WorkManager</res-type> 
   <res-auth>Container</res-auth> 
   <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope> 
</resource-ref>
```

...

So you can use the `@ejbgen:resource-ref` task to generate this in the ejb-jar.xml, as documented [here](http://beust.com/ejbgen/#ant-task)

Comment: As said in my question, ejb-jar.xml is generated by the ejbgen tool. So I can not add the work manager definition here...